# Can't assign values to Player Object?

Tags: java, arrays, oop

While I am still a novice programmer, I am fairly confident when it comes to initializing objects. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out why I get an error in this code. Could someone help me out? the line: Players player = new Players("Phil", [0][0] , false); is where I get an error.

```
public class Players {
private String player;
private int [][] position;
private boolean turn;
public static void main(String[]args){
    Players player = new Players("Phil", [0][0] , false);
}
public Players(String player, int[][] position, boolean turn){
    this.player = player;
    this.position = position;
    this.turn = turn;
}
public String getPlayer(){
    return player;
}
public void setPlayer(String player){
    this.player = player;
}
public int [][] getPosition(){
    return position;
}
public void setPosition(int [][] position){
    this.position = position;
}
public boolean getTurn(){
    return turn;
}
public void setTurn(boolean turn){
    this.turn = turn;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[0][0]` is not valid syntax. Use `new int[0][0]` instead.

You're trying to use a 2 dimensional array to represent a position.

---

It would probably be better to use 2 integers to represent your position:

```
public class Players {
    private String player;
    private int x, y; // <---
    private boolean turn;
    ...
    public Players(String player, int x, int y, boolean turn){
        this.player = player;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.turn = turn;
    }
    ...
}
```

And create a player with:

```
Player player = new Players("Phil", 0, 0, false);
```

---

Alternatively, you could make a class that represents coordinates in 2D space:

```
public class Coordinate {
    public final int x, y;

    public Coordinate(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

public class player {
    ...
    private Coordinate position;
    ...
    public Players(String player, Coordinate position, boolean turn){
        this.player = player;
        this.position = position;
        this.turn = turn;
    }   
    ...
}
```

Then create a player with:

```
Player player = new Players("Phil", new Coordinate(0, 0), false);
```

Comment: I think in the long run, this might be the way I want to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to write your static void main is:

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
        Players player = new Players("Phil", new int[0][0] , false);
}
```

> int[][]
>   is a declarative form, it just declare the object as int a for example
>
> new int[0][0] is used to initialize the object

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but the other answer might be easier for me down the road in the bigger picture. What a simple oversight that is. I should probably get some sleep before posting again! Thanks!